# Ruby 1.9 unicode escapes in Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

I just upgraded an old project to Ruby 1.9.3. I'm having a bunch of trouble with unicode strings. It boils down to:

```
p = "\\username"; "Any String".match(/#{p}/)
```

That works in 1.8, and returns nil as expected. However, in 1.9 it throws:

```
ArgumentError: invalid Unicode escape
```

I'm trying to match `'\u'` in a string. I thought the two backslashes will escape it from registering as a unicode.

What am I missing here?

Edit: Single quotes don't work too:

```
1.9.3p429 :002 > p = '\\username'; "Any String".match(/#{p}/)
ArgumentError: invalid Unicode escape
from (irb):2
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `/#{p}/` it means `p` will be interpreted as a regular expression. Since your `p` is now equal to `\username`, then this Regexp compilation will fail (since it IS an invalid Unicode escape sequence):

```
>> Regexp.new "\\username"
RegexpError: invalid Unicode escape: /\username/
```

I.e. doing `/#{p}/` is equal to writing `/\username/`.

Therefore you have to escape `p` from any regular expressions so it will be interpreted correctly:

```
"Any String".match(/#{Regexp.escape(p)}/)
```

Or just:

```
"Any String".match(Regexp.escape(p))
```